# Updating Nvidia drivers 11.10 (nvidia 290.xxx.xxx)

Tags: nvidia

Hi I installed NVIDIA drivers using terminal. I added the newest repositories, to ensure getting the newest driver, once that was complete, I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This started the download and successfully installed the (290.xx.xxx) version. The issue I have is when opening X-server application it still shows NVIDIA driver version 173.14.30.

Can someone walk me through correcting this so it corresponds to the driver installed?

Thanks

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: @Jesse if any of these 'answers', answered your question, please accept one of them!

Answer (score 3):

To update, to the latest Nvidia drivers run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried going to the restricted drivers program (`jockey`, listed as "Additional Drivers"),  The driver may have been installed but not activated.  I know there is a command line command that would activate the driver, but I don't remember what that command is.  Since it was downloaded and installed, the restricted drivers program should show it, just tell that program to activate the driver, if it needs to download it again, it will, if not, it will just activate it for you.